# Sort data frame by multiple columns in R, case insensitive

Tags: r

So I have 3 vectors:

```
n<-10e3    
ch<-append(LETTERS,letters)

a<-sample(ch,n,replace=TRUE)    
b<-sample(ch,n,replace=TRUE)    
c<-sample(ch,n,replace=TRUE)

df<-data.frame(a,b,c)
```

And now i want it to be sorted by all these columns. I found:

```
df[with(df, order(a,b,c)), ]
```

but, problem is, it's case sensitive, and outcome looks like that:

```
5359 A a b    
7325 A a B    
7200 A a g   
9122 A a V   
2144 A a W    
5984 A a z    
8349 A A e    
5215 A A E    
4007 A A f    
3099 A A H    
3220 A A i    
7080 A A N    
4963 A A r   
9159 A A V    
4219 A A w    
9723 A b b    
4463 A b h    
7894 A b V    
3765 A B a    
8772 A B b
```

As you see, for example, it puts "A A e" after "A a z". How to make it case insensitive?

Comment: use `tolower` or `toupper` on the columns in `order`

Comment: This is the start of a good question, Kamil, thank you for spending time making it mostly reproducible! However, some thoughts: (1) when using random data, if you want us to be able to reproduce your random data, please use `set.seed(42)` (or some number) before pulling randomness. (2) We definitely don't need to generate frames with `10e3` rows, I'd think 8-10 would more than suffice. In this case, I know you have a specific example to bring out, so ... perhaps you don't need randomness at all, you could use `data.frame(a = c(...), b = c(...), c = c(...))`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind going over to dplyr forms

```
@library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   as_tibble() %>% 
   mutate(lowcase = tolower(paste(a,b,c))) %>% 
   arrange(lowcase)
# A tibble: 10,000 x 4
   a     b     c     lowcase
   <fct> <fct> <fct> <chr>  
 1 a     A     D     a a d  
 2 A     A     L     a a l  
 3 a     a     N     a a n  
 4 A     A     n     a a n  
 5 a     a     w     a a w  
 6 A     a     X     a a x  
 7 A     A     Y     a a y  
 8 a     A     Y     a a y  
 9 A     b     A     a b a  
10 A     B     a     a b a
```